# how to run command in bash as root?

Tags: linux, bash

i made  an script for my developers inside /root/prepare_server.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="/var/www/html/crm/cicrm/cache/
/var/www/html/crm/cicrm/data/
/var/www/html/crm/cicrm/logs/
/var/www/html/crmtest/cicrm/cache/
/var/www/html/crmtest/cicrm/data/
/var/www/html/crmtest/cicrm/logs/"

for f in $FILES
do
echo "processing $f" 1>&2
if [[ ! -e $f ]]; then
    mkdir $dir
elif [[ ! -d $f ]]; then
    echo "$f already exists but is not a directory" 1>&2
fi
done

chown -R manager:phpdev /var/www/html/crm/
chown -R manager:phpdev /var/www/html/crmtest/
chown -R manager:phpdev /var/redmine/crmGit/
chown -R manager:phpdev /var/redmine/owncloudGit/
chmod -R 770 /var/redmine/crmGit/
chmod -R 770 /var/redmine/owncloudGit/
chmod -R 770 /var/www/html/crm/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/crm/cicrm/cache/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/crm/cicrm/data/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/crm/cicrm/logs/
chmod -R 770 /var/www/html/crmtest/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/crmtest/cicrm/cache/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/crmtest/cicrm/data/
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/crmtest/cicrm/logs/
```

and the whole dirs is only owned by me :
manager:phpdev

usually when my developers update all files with git, the permission is changing to developer:developer,

how my user (developer:developer) can run my script ?

Comment: `man sudo` -- you can give the developers the ability to run that one script.  Warning:  Script files are horribly insecure -- if someone wanted to do some damage, they could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sudo`, you can write rules in `/etc/sudoers` file，for example something like:

```
# format: user host = (run as) NOPASSWD: path
developer ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /root/prepare_server.sh
```

[`man sudoers`](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/5/sudoers/) for more detail.

Or you can use `SUID` to run that script as root:

```
chown root /root/prepare_server.sh
chmod u+s /root/prepare_server.sh
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Comment: work well like i want, i always got error using sudo before because the difficulties sample out there ..

Answer (score 0):

Install the software package [`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/) on the machine, which allows you to grant permission for non-root users to run specific commands as root.

Then, grant your developer permission to run that specific script.

Comment: can sudo give only chown and chmod only for certain folder instead off all folder, i mean developer can only chown and chmod only for /var/www/html but cannot do it in my /home/manager ?

Comment: That type of control is more in the scope of SELinux than `sudo`.  However, you can take the already-written `prepare_server` script, place it somewhere appropriate (`/usr/local/sbin` comes to mind), and grant the developer access to run *that script and only that script* with root privileges using `sudo`.

Comment: when i give developer the function of sudo chmod and sudo chown as root, can they only use it inside certain folder and prevent it to other folders?

Comment: @kreamik Perhaps a chroot jail or making sure these files they need to chmod have proper filesystem permissions that allow their own user to modify them.

Comment: i cannot make sure for the filesystem because we use git for that folder that can change the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

[`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)

Set up your sudoers file to your liking.   You can set it up so they can only run certain commands and they can do it without the password.

Comment: can sudo give only chown and chmod only for certain folder instead off all folder, i mean developer can only chown and chmod only for /var/www/html but cannot do it in my /home/manager ?

Comment: @kreamik Sudo cannot do that by itself, but a good unix admin could arrange any number of solutions.  If it's linux, then perhaps a selinux policy might suffice.  If that's to tall an order, you might set up a chroot jail for the app.  This might be a better question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: @kreamik Honestly, if you're worried about what they'll do with their root powers, then giving them the ability to run *anything* as root is a bad idea.